# Where to put a live video feed in our app

Tags: maps, video, placement, location, live

I need to incorporate the live video feed from a camera into our app (which runs on Desktop but also tablets), which is basically a navigation tool with a map view, and some controls on the right side.

The live video is coming from a camera attached to an autonomous device (small boat) which is controlled and monitored via the application and is located somewhere on the map.

There is a dedicated space allocated for the video feed, but regardless what I try to do, it still looks ugly:

- If I put the video feed on the left, there is a huge black space after that,
- if I put it on the right, the black space is before and
- if I put it in the middle there is black space before and after. If I put the video feed in a separate window it covers the map :(

So, now I'm really clueless what to do :) ...

The question is: what is the community's recommendation for situations like this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The question is: what is the live video for?

Comment: @Levano edited, see inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided the user is able to zoom in / out, and move this map to be able to see what they want, I would suggest that you put the video feed on top of the map in the top corner.

If you look at google maps you will see that they also overlay controls on their maps to avoid blank spaces (e.g.the satellite image in the bottom left).

[image: google maps image]

Comment: ^^^^ here is your answer